# switch statement within function returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I have following code in my page:

```
function amAction(action, key, val){
        switch (action){
            case "set":
                localStorage.setItem(key,val);
                break;
            case "get":
                localStorage.getItem(key);
                break;
            case "remove":
                localStorage.removeItem(key);
                break;
            default:
                console.log(`${action}: ${key}: ${val}`);
                
        }
    }
```

when I try to get the values I am getting undefined. Why?

Comment: You call `getItem`, but don't capture the value that it returns. And your function has no `return` statement.

Comment: You need to use the return keyword to return something from a function.

Comment: Why not simply `const amAction = (action, key, val) => localStorage[action + "Item"](key, val);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the value in your get method like so:

```
function amAction(action, key, val){
       switch (action){
            case "set":
                localStorage.setItem(key,val);
                break;
            case "get":
                return localStorage.getItem(key);
                break;
            case "remove":
                localStorage.removeItem(key);
                break;
            default:
                console.log(`${action}: ${key}: ${val}`);
                
        }
    }
```